# Check if Progress Bar Equals Amount in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I know this should be simple, but I am trying to check if a progress-bar equals 100%. I can't seem to trigger an alert if it does.

```js
var bar = $('.progress-bar').text(val);
var val = percentage + '%';
var percentage=1;
   if(bar == 100){
       alert("100");
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10"aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%">100%</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var percentage = someFunctionToGetPercentage();

    $('.progress-bar').text(percentage + '%');

    if (parseInt($('.progress-bar').text()) == 100) { // or $('.progress-bar').text() == '100%'
        alert(100);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eb0xnyrk/)

Comment: why not? what's the issue?

Comment: This script must be added in the head section after including the jquery framework

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eb0xnyrk/ There is a problem with your understanding about js and html.. please read more tutorials about js/jquery in order to be able to create these scripts.. What you have tried is a basic script.. you should be able to do it by yourself